# How can I find function usage in files other than go?

Tags: go, goland

I am using a custom language (antha) which gets transpiled to go.

Antha script files end in `.an` and get transpiled to`.go`

I have a function in a `.go` file and I want to find its usages in `.an` files.

How do change the "find usage" feature of Gogland to include the `.an` files? Currently it only searches in the `.go` transpiled scripts.

Comment: If this is even possible (unlikely), it would depend on antha tools, not Go tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A language plugin that understands antha would need to be created / installed in order for that feature to work, otherwise the IDE has no way to understand how to make that feature work. If you wish to learn about plugin development for IntelliJ Platform, you can [start here](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics.html).

Comment: Antha is essentially Go with a few minor differences (`protocol` instead of `package`), which is why I assumed there would be an easier way to do this.